# Set an Integer value from one class to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been trying to set an Integer value from one class to another like below, but i can't do this.

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController {

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) int m_selrow;
+ (void)setRowSelected : (int)selecetedRow;

@end

@implementation ClassA 

+ (void)setRowSelected : (int)selecetedRow {
    m_selrow = selecetedRow;

}
@end

//Accessing from different Class,

//Class B implementation:

[ClassA setRowSelected:indexPath.row];
```

Problem is, it says "m_selrow is use of undeclared identifier from setRowSelected() method. How to properly use the variable and set it from another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface should inherit from something, I changed it to NSObject

**I also added static declartion to of member field to class A**

After fixing those, it works smoothly.

Here are my changes:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject{

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) int m_selrow;
+ (void)setRowSelected : (int)selecetedRow;

@end

@implementation ClassA
static int m_selrow;

+ (void)setRowSelected : (int)selecetedRow {
    m_selrow = selecetedRow;
    NSLog(@"============= > %d", m_selrow);

}
@end

[ClassA setRowSelected: 1];
```

Comment: No, the problem is not that. Problem is, it says "m_selrow is use of undeclared identifier. I was asking how to properly use the variable and set it from another class.

Comment: Opps. My bad. I updated my answer and corrected the case.